# Forgot my password

Tags: applications

I have installed sim change alert app a month ago, but now I forgot my password. Can anyone tell me how to get a new password in sim change alert app

Answer (score 1):

Close the app and go to **Settings -> Apps -> Sim Change Alert**. Then select <kbd>Clear data</kbd>. This will permanently delete all files, settings, and databases associated with that app. Next time you start the app it'll be like when you first installed it.